# how to know exact number of elements in C# List collection

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I'm passing from my view page one to five images to controller.

```
  <input type="file" name="Images" /><br />
  <input type="file" name="Images" /><br />
  <input type="file" name="Images" /><br />
  <input type="file" name="Images" /><br />
  <input type="file" name="Images" /><br />
```

I receive on my controller like this

```
 IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images
```

and sending this data together with other data to myDomainModel
I tried with this

```
List<Photo> Photos = new List<Photo>();
for (int i = 0; i < Images.Count(); i++)
{
   foreach (var image in Images)
   {
      Photo p = new Photo();
      p.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
      p.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
      image.InputStream.Read(p.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);

      Photos.Add(p);
   }                
}
```

But Images.Count() return capacity of whole list, so when I'm post let say 2 images instead of five I'm in trouble cause code trying to loop 5 times.

**So, question is how to get number of elements in list. Not capacity.**

Thank you.

Comment: What's the point of that outer for-loop? It seems that you are looping over the collection in the outer and the inner foreach loop, so you are squaring the number of images: Images.Count = 5 => Photos.Count = 25; Images.Count = 2 => Photos.Count = 4.

Comment: I've tried without for loop on first place. So you're suggestion is ?

Comment: Get rid of the for-loop. And keep the foreach-loop. If the problem is that some of the images are empty, then maybe wrap the contents of the foreach-loop in an if(image.ContentLength > 0) {...} block. That way it will only add images that actually have content. It would be better if the code on the page only submitted the right number of images though.

Comment: I was convinced that this approach would work, right now I tried this code but no luck. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. If I select 2 images to upload inside foreach loop on third attempt error is thrown on line if (image.ContentLength > 0) Bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what is going on. It sounds like the source page is adding empty images that the user didn't submit? If that's the case, then you it would be better to fix this there.

Failing that, then this should work:

```
var Photos = new List<Photo>(); 

foreach (var image in Images) 
{ 
   if(image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
   {
      Photo p = new Photo(); 
      p.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType; 
      p.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength]; 
      image.InputStream.Read(p.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength); 

      Photos.Add(p); 
   }
}
```

Comment: I was convinced that this approach would work, right now I tried this code but no luck.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I select 2 images to upload inside foreach loop on third attempt error is thrown on line if (image.ContentLength > 0)

Bit confused

Comment: Ah, in that case, you need to check if the image is null before you access the ContentLength property. I've edited the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Can you test if `ContentLength` is not null (or is there any other property to check if "Image" is submitted) ?

Then you can use Linq and do : `int nbImages = Images.Count(i => i.ContentLength > 0);`

Comment: I'm looking in debug mode, images are correctly submited, and if I post two images, then in this loop first two attempts are ok, Photos collection is filled successfully but since it reads capacity of 5 elements on third attempt is broken.

Comment: Actually this helps

    if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)

Thank you all, problem solved.